# Angular & Typescript - Date input validation in the 'Input' field

Tags: angular, typescript, date, angular5, ng-bootstrap

My Angular5 program includes an `input` field for entering date. I am using `NgbDateStruct` and `NgbCalendar` from **ng-bootstrap**. Though there is a calendar, for picking the date, when the user manually enters input to the date field, it doesn't validate.

That is, in the input field allotted for entering the date, the user should not be able to enter a text or garbage data. But right now, the user is able to enter any kind of data.

To do this client-side validation, I tried using `<input type = "date">`, but the `input type = date` is **not supported in IE 11 and earlier versions.**

There were several solutions available in JQuery and JavaScript. But I cannot use JQuery and JavaScript in my Angular+TypeScript program.

What is the way to validate the input field for **Date** such that the user will not be able to enter in the input field anything other than a valid date in **Typescript**?

I tried the following workaround in TypeScript, but ended up with an error:

**app.component.ts**:

```
validateDate() {
     const regExp = /^(\d{4})\/(\d\d?)\/(\d\d?)$/;
    if (((this.fromDate).toString()).match(regExp)) {
        console.log('Valid Date');
    }
}
```

The error I got was:

> [ts] - Property 'match' does not exist on type 'NgbDateStruct'

where `this.fromDate` is the date input I am receiving from the view.

**HTML:**

```
<div class = "input-group date">
    <input class = "form-control" [(ngModel)] = "fromDate" ngbDatepicker #d = "ngbDatepicker" onmousedown = "validateDate()">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steffi, your variable fromDate is an object {year:##,month:##,day:##},

To check if is a valid date you simply ask about year,month and day.

e.g. In a submit you can do

```
submit()
{
    let validDate:boolean=this.fromDate.year && this.fromDate.month && this.fromDate.day
    let data={
       fecha:validDate?''+this.fromDate.year+'/'+this.fromDate.month+'/'+this.fromDate.day:null;
    }
 }
```

Comment: I tried your code. It shows me error that "what is fecha?" and there is nothing as bool..

Comment: it's not date =, is date: (just corrected in the code), I only tru to make an object NOTE: (sorry someone 've improved my code too and do not remember who is, thanks to her / him

Comment: I still get an error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'boolean'."

Comment: try (this.fromDate.year!=0)

Comment: Can you please tell, what is the purpose of 'fecha' in your code? I keep getting errors that "Cannot find name fecha. Did you mean fetch?"

Comment: Got it!Good approach